# Simple Filter Function

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to find a function $f(x)$ when $x>1$ which gives $0$ when $x=1$ and $200$ for all positive integers $x>1$.

i.e.

- $f(1) = 0 $
- $f(2) = 200$
- $f(3) = 200 $
- $f(4) = 200$

and etc..

Is there any simple way to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\displaystyle f(t) = 200 u(t-1)$$

Where $u(t)$ is the [*Heaviside Unit Step*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) function.

Here is a [WA plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+200+Unitstep%5Bt-1%5D).

Comment: $\large \checkmark +1$

Comment: $\LARGE{+1}....$

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend! Regards

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want a smooth function, you can use
$$
f(t)=200\left(1-\frac{\sin(\pi (t-1))}{\pi (t-1)}\right)
$$